# Evaluating sequence with a fitted model using depmixS4 in R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

If I have fit a model `mf` with `depmix()` and `fit()` using `depmixS4` package, and I want to know the log-likelihood of generating a given sequence `s`, how should I do?

I know in the `HiddenMarkov` package I can use `forwardback(s, mf$Pi, mf$...)$LL` to get the log-likelihood, but I find the `forwardbackward()` function in `depmixS4` does not work similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the way myself, as first time working with S4...

Firstly initialize a model (depmix obj) with `depmix()`, and then update it with parameters in the fitted `mf` using `setpars()`. After that the `forwardbackward()` will work

```
init_mod <- depmix(respones, data, nstates) ## no solid value
mod <- setpars(init_mod, getpars(fm))
forwardbackward(mod)
```

---

Anyone knows better solution plz tell me...